# PostgreSQL - make two transactions run at the same time

Tags: postgresql, concurrency

I need to make two sessions (two files) run concurrently (at the same time). Is there a way to do this using pg_sleep or some other function like "delayExecutionUntil(x_time)"?

Comment: If this us for testing, have the test app or OS start multiple requests simultaneously. If that doesn't reliably work, bombard the server until you get the situation you want

Comment: Yes, thats what im wondering, how is it possible to start multiple requests simultaneously with in postgres?

Comment: You need to open two connections. One for each transaction

Comment: how can I ensure that they are run at the same time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get two transactions at the (almost) exact same time, you could schedule two or more invocations of [psql](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/app-psql.html) at the same time in a Linux shell with the [`at` command](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl1_atq.htm).

Like:

```
at '08:00 01.12.2012' -f script.sql
```

(The required timestamp format may depend on your system locale.)
Where `script.sql` contains something like:

```
psql mydb -p 5432 -c "INSERT INTO tbl (col) VALUES ('foo');
```

Just with a lot more rows to provoke the collisions you are after ..

Comment: Awesome, so if I do that for two different clients they will both run at that time? I'm assuming if they are on the same client they can't run concurrently.

Comment: @Lebowski156: if you start `psql` twice, those two scripts *will* run concurrently.

Answer (score 1):

You can use table locks (see `LOCK` command in the docs) to synchronize the stuff:

- Connection "Controller" locks the first table the real transactions will use.
- create new "Worker-A" connection and start your transaction. It will block on the locked table.
- create new "Worker-B" connection and start your transaction. It will block on the locked table.
- the "Controller" connection releases the lock.
- "Worker-A" and "Worker-B" should immediately start working - if their concurrency setting allows this of course.