# PostgreSQL - Start a transaction in specific time

Tags: sql, postgresql, concurrency, transactions, plpgsql

I search for a way to start a `Function` or `Transaction` in a specific time (**in order to test concurrent access**), but i don't find a clear way i find here [PostgreSQL - make two transactions run at the same time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13662173/postgresql-make-two-transactions-run-at-the-same-time), something to execute a Script with linux in specific time, but this not helpful if you are using windows or another OS.

I create a simple way but i'm not sure if this have problems or not :

I create a function that take `start-date`, then in this function i use `pg_sleep(sleep_time)` to block my action until that time, so the idea is simple :

```
sleep_time = start_date - current_date
```

Here is the function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION start__my_job_in_specific_time(start_time timestamp) RETURNS INTEGER AS $$
     BEGIN
       PERFORM pg_sleep((select extract(epoch from (start_time - (SELECT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)))));
       -- now execute my actions
       UPDATE sch_lock.table_concurente set max_value = max_value + 1 
       WHERE id = (SELECT id FROM sch_lock.table_concurente ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1);
       RETURN (SELECT MAX(max_value) FROM sch_lock.table_concurente);
     END;
     $$ 
LANGUAGE plpgsql;

-- start my function at 2017-02-20 12:03:30
SELECT * FROM start__my_job_in_specific_time('2017-02-20 11:03:30');
```

This work fine and the transaction work in the exact time.

> **My Question :** is there any similar way in postgres better than this.

Comment: there's https://github.com/citusdata/pg_cron project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you probably better use `clock_timestamp()` then - `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` will return ts of transaction start, not function run start:

```
t=# begin;
select pg_sleep(2);
do
$$
begin
  raise info '%',concat('CURRENT_TIMESTAMP: ',CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,' realtime: ',clock_timestamp());
end;
$$
;

end;
BEGIN
 pg_sleep
----------

(1 row)

INFO:  CURRENT_TIMESTAMP: 2017-02-20 11:40:59.294505+00 realtime: 2017-02-20 11:41:01.295338+00
DO
COMMIT
```

Answer (score 2):

From PostgreSQL 9.6 on, you can [export and import database snapshots](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-admin.html#FUNCTIONS-SNAPSHOT-SYNCHRONIZATION), which allows you to effectively start two transactions at the same instant.

You'd have to communicate the snapshot name from one program to the other though.

Of course that only makes sense if the second transaction is started while the first is still running, so it could be used in addition to your method.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do something very similar to the answer you linked in your question.  Just use whatever scheduling mechanism is available in your OS to schedule up two psql commands to execute at the same time.  In Windows, use the built in Task Scheduler.

Alternatively if you're capable, you could create a simple application that executes the commands on separate connections and threads.  Just use a synchronization object to synchronize the command execution.